# How to mass update status of many objects in a performant fashion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Our use case is much similar to Google email. I have read 8K out of 10K emails in my Inbox. I would like to mark the rest of 2K emails as **READ**. How can I effectively update the rows whose status bit needs to be modified (since at-least with Google, it asks you whether you want to mark all the messages as Read including 10K messages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`update_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001798)

```
Billing.update_all( "read = true", "read = false" )
```

Comment: @Joe: this is correct answer... btw You can also do: user.posts.update_all("privacy='private'")